# LED not working on some sockets

Tags: electrical, lighting

So I've gotten one of those wifibulbs that you can change the color through an app and all that.

My problem was that it works with table lamps and standing lamps but it doesn't with the hanging pendant (I guess that's how a room lamp is called?). The bulb comes with an e-27 end and it also has an e-14 adapter which I bought it for the pendant. I've tried the adapter and it works fine in one of my lamps, so it's not that.

Actually there are three hanging pendants, and I was going to use only one. I have used it 2 empty and one with a different bulb and by that I know it's not because of not using the three sockets.

I don't know what could be wrong, what do you think?

P.S all the rooms have those types of pendants.

Answer (score 2):

> **I don't what could be wrong, what do you think?**

I think it is probably incompatible with some other device on that circuit, such as a dimmer, a switch-locator or something else.

If this is the case it may be best to take/send the bulb back to the retailer and change it for a dimmer-compatible LED bulb.

---

It might be that your E27 to E14 adapter only makes proper contact when gravity is pushing the bulb into the adapter (standing upright) instead of pulling out away (hanging down)

If this is the case, I'd replace the E27 bulb with one that has an E14 fitting to match your ceiling fittings. Or change the ceiling fitting to one that takes E27 bulbs.

Comment: I don't have a dimmer actually. I'll use it with my table lamp then.